# Book about mind-to-mind jumpers

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm searching for the name of a book where a young man was found by some agency. They told him that some people can jump into another person's mind. The eyes were important. They proved him in public party (a girl jumped into our hero and climbed on high furniture). It was in London if I'm not wrong.

There was another organization which went to kill all jumpers. Young man has to run. He was caught and he was trapped in a paralyzed body. He has to fight with mad mind of the body. He escaped (he could use skills from other people), he found two androids (only one was working) on crashed army transport.

I'm almost sure that the name is "Jumper" but I've found only story about teleport guys. In searching novel there was no teleport. Only mind jumping.

I hope it is enough to recognize. It's my obsession now ;-)

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: Just so you know, I typed in **mind control comics** to find out what you may have been looking for, and I tell you now, don't click on any of the search results if you ever search that up!! In fact, don't search that up **at all**!

Comment: You are evil! :-P
Yes I've had to check it. And YES, don't look inside. Mind control comics is not a Sci-Fi action book :-D

Comment: *why did you look it up????*

Comment: You wrote "don't look" – do you know any another sentence more interesting ;-) I had a lucky, there was a banner and could stop there!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I haven't read it, but because it has "jumpers" in the title, and because it seems to be about minds jumping into other people's bodies, I'm going to guess that you're looking for [*Skinjumpers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1615774), a 2013 novel by [Michael D. Griffiths](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?138221), published by M-Brane Press. From the [publisher's blog](http://www.mbranesf.com/2013/05/skinjumpers-published.html), the preface to *Skinjumpers*:

> I first encountered the world of *Skinjumpers*—a strange and dangerous milieu—in a short story that the author submitted at the end of 2008 to my then-fledgling zine *M-Brane SF*. The story “A Clone of a Different Color” introduced New Cluster, a decaying city in an unspecified future and location, run by a corrupt and authoritarian police-state structure that resembles a mafia as much as a government and which is shot through with struggles among various factions. But it was not the post-cyberpunk veneer of this tale that appealed to me, but rather its subversive core conceit that people can move their consciousnesses, their very selves, from one body to another and somehow remain whole.
>
> Specifically, the first Skinjumper tale evoked a topic that I’d wondered about a lot before I’d read that story: if I somehow change bodies (a perennial fantasy of mine), am I still *me*? Is there even actually a “me” outside my physicality? This remains a vexing question that we may—within the lifetimes of people reading this—have answered for us when we find out whether or not it is possible to separate consciousness from the body, move it into another body or possibly into a computer construct and learn whether that consciousness can survive intact or if it will be radically altered by the nature of its new physical form. I’ve wondered whether my “selfness” is really somehow a wholly different thing than my body in the way that humans tend to believe it is or if all I am is simply the compound of the literal physical stuff of my body. Is that which makes me an individual, a consciousness, actually a real thing that can be taken out of my body by some sort of futuristic instrumentality and moved elsewhere? Or is my body’s physical gender, its chromosomes, its genitalia, its sexual orientation, its age and condition and experience inseparable from the “me” of me? We don’t know this answer yet in the real world, but in the world of *Skinjumpers*, the answer is *no*: we *can* separate from our bodies and remain ourselves. We can even become *even more our real selves* by doing so.
>
> In Michael D. Griffiths’ series of Skinjumper short stories that I published in *M-Brane SF*, and in this novel, a lot of questions are left unanswered. One is not given a detailed rationale as to why things are the way they are in New Cluster, but the reader doesn’t really need one either. The titular Skinjumpers threaten the social order and draw the fire of the authorities because (among other reasons) they are sex-rebels. They not only change bodies and cheat death by “jumping” into cloned replacements, but they can change physical gender. Some of them choose to do so permanently. In this story, you will meet Erin, a young woman whom you may underestimate at first because of the way she chooses to present herself. She is the long-term girlfriend of our protagonist Dak. But Dak has a particular sexual kink that is fabulously enabled in this world: he is oriented toward men who inhabit female bodies. Erin was once a guy and still somehow is even within her unambiguously feminine physical form. But she seems to not quite fit into our current understanding of LGBTQ-ness either. She and he are a shade different than what is enabled by or even understood in our so-called “real” world. Underneath their more or less conventional gender self-portrayals, they are both fascinatingly queer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems interesting but I don't thing that is my story. I guess I read my book 10 maybe 20 years ago. It was rather action story not sexual uncertainty. Protagonist can jump into women (he runs by jumping to many people, his enemies detect him analyzing a series of fainting) but there was no any sexual context if I'm not wrong.